# How to disable/kill and get funds from a smart contract that I'm the owner?

Tags: blockchain, contract-design, selfdestruct

I have a smart contract that is not being used anymore and still have funds. I would like to withdraw them and destruct or disable it.
I didn't write the code but I'm the owner and the programmer forgot to input this option before launching it!

The code is as follows:

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2020-05-07
*/

pragma solidity >=0.4.24;

contract Matrix {
    struct User {
        uint id;
        address referrer;
        uint personalMatrixCnt;
        uint personalMatrixNum;
        uint personalMatrixFills;
        uint totalReferrals;
        uint levelsOpen;
 }

mapping(uint => uint) public LEVEL_PRICE;
mapping(uint => uint) public LEVEL_SLOTS;
mapping(uint => uint) public EXTRA_SLOTS;

mapping(address => User) public users;
mapping(uint => address) public binaryUsers;
mapping(uint => address) public usersById;

mapping(address => mapping (uint => uint)) public positionsByAddress;
mapping(address => uint) public positionsByAddressCnt;
mapping(uint => uint) public binaryPositionsLevels;

uint public lastUserId = 2;
uint public lastBinaryId = 1;
uint public lastPersonalMatrixId = 2;
address public owner;

uint REGISTRATION_COST = 0.05 ether;

event Registration(address indexed user, address indexed referrer, uint indexed userId, uint referrerId);
event LevelUpgraded(address indexed user, uint indexed userId, uint indexed level);
event LevelFilled(address indexed user, uint indexed userId, uint indexed level);
event Transfer(address indexed user, uint indexed userId, uint indexed amount);

function isUserExists(address user) public view returns (bool) {
    return (users[user].id != 0);
}

constructor(address ownerAddress) public {
    owner = ownerAddress;

    User memory user = User({
        id: 1,
        referrer: address(0),
        personalMatrixCnt: 0,
        personalMatrixNum: 1,
        personalMatrixFills: 0,
        totalReferrals: 0,
        levelsOpen: 1
        });

    users[ownerAddress] = user;
    usersById[1] = ownerAddress;

    LEVEL_PRICE[1] = 0.05 ether;
    LEVEL_PRICE[2] = 0.1 ether;
    LEVEL_PRICE[3] = 0.2 ether;
    LEVEL_PRICE[4] = 1 ether;
    LEVEL_PRICE[5] = 6 ether;
    LEVEL_PRICE[6] = 50 ether;
    LEVEL_PRICE[7] = 50 ether;
    LEVEL_PRICE[8] = 100 ether;
    LEVEL_PRICE[9] = 400 ether;
    LEVEL_PRICE[10] = 1600 ether;

    LEVEL_SLOTS[1] = 2;
    LEVEL_SLOTS[2] = 4;
    LEVEL_SLOTS[3] = 8;
    LEVEL_SLOTS[4] = 16;
    LEVEL_SLOTS[5] = 32;
    LEVEL_SLOTS[6] = 2;
    LEVEL_SLOTS[7] = 4;
    LEVEL_SLOTS[8] = 8;
    LEVEL_SLOTS[9] = 16;
    LEVEL_SLOTS[10] = 32;

    EXTRA_SLOTS[1] = 0;
    EXTRA_SLOTS[2] = 1;
    EXTRA_SLOTS[3] = 6;
    EXTRA_SLOTS[4] = 20;
    EXTRA_SLOTS[5] = 200;
    EXTRA_SLOTS[6] = 200;
    EXTRA_SLOTS[7] = 400;
    EXTRA_SLOTS[8] = 2000;
    EXTRA_SLOTS[9] = 16000;
    EXTRA_SLOTS[10] = 124000;
}

function reg(address referrer) public payable {
    registration(msg.sender, referrer);
}

function purchasePosition() public payable {
    require(msg.value == 0.05 ether, "purchase cost 0.05");
    require(isUserExists(msg.sender), "user not exists");

    updateBinaryMatrix(msg.sender);
}

function registration(address userAddress, address referrerAddress) private {
    require(msg.value == 0.1 ether, "registration cost 0.1");
    require(!isUserExists(userAddress), "user exists");
    require(isUserExists(referrerAddress), "referrer not exists");

    uint32 size;
    assembly {
        size := extcodesize(userAddress)
    }
    require(size == 0, "cannot be a contract");

    users[userAddress] = User({
        id: lastUserId,
        referrer: referrerAddress,
        levelsOpen: 1,
        personalMatrixCnt: 0,
        personalMatrixFills: 0,
        personalMatrixNum: lastPersonalMatrixId,
        totalReferrals: 0
        });
    usersById[lastUserId] = userAddress;

    lastUserId++;
    lastPersonalMatrixId++;

    updatePersonalMatrix(referrerAddress);
    updateBinaryMatrix(userAddress);

    emit Registration(userAddress, referrerAddress, users[userAddress].id, users[referrerAddress].id);
}

function updatePersonalMatrix(address referrer) private {
    users[referrer].totalReferrals++;
    if (users[referrer].personalMatrixCnt < 2) {
        payRegDividends(referrer);
        users[referrer].personalMatrixCnt++;
    } else if (users[referrer].personalMatrixCnt == 2) {
        updateBinaryMatrix(referrer);
        users[referrer].personalMatrixCnt++;
    } else {
        if (users[referrer].referrer == address(0)) {
            payRegDividends(referrer);
        } else {
            updatePersonalMatrix(users[referrer].referrer);
        }
        users[referrer].personalMatrixCnt = 0;
        users[referrer].personalMatrixNum = lastPersonalMatrixId;
        users[referrer].personalMatrixFills++;
        lastPersonalMatrixId++;
    }
}

function payRegDividends(address user) private {
    emit Transfer(user, users[user].id, REGISTRATION_COST);
    address(uint160(user)).transfer(REGISTRATION_COST);
}

function updateBinaryMatrix(address user) private {
    positionsByAddress[user][positionsByAddressCnt[user]] = lastBinaryId;
    positionsByAddressCnt[user]++;
    binaryPositionsLevels[lastBinaryId] = 1;

    binaryUsers[lastBinaryId] = user;
    lastBinaryId++;

    uint div = 1;
    uint level = 0;
    uint initIndex = lastBinaryId-1;
    uint index = lastBinaryId-1;

    while (level < 5) {
        level++;
        div *= 2;

        if (index % div == div - 1) {
            index = index / div;

            if (index != 0) {
                binaryPositionsLevels[index] = level;
                fillLevel(binaryUsers[index], level);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    index = initIndex;

    while (level < 10) {
        level++;
        div *= 2;

        if (index % div == div - 1) {
            index = index / div;

            if (index != 0) {
                binaryPositionsLevels[index] = level;
                fillLevel(binaryUsers[index], level);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}

function fillLevel(address user, uint level) private {
    emit LevelFilled(user, users[user].id, level);

    level = level + 1;

    uint payment = LEVEL_PRICE[level - 1] * LEVEL_SLOTS[level - 1];

    if (users[user].levelsOpen < level) {
        users[user].levelsOpen++;
        emit LevelUpgraded(user, users[user].id, level);
    }

    payment -= LEVEL_PRICE[level];
    payment -= REGISTRATION_COST * EXTRA_SLOTS[level-1];

    if (level > 2) {
        emit Transfer(user, users[user].id, payment);

        address(uint160(user)).transfer(payment);
    }

    uint i = 0;
    while (i < EXTRA_SLOTS[level-1]) {
        updateBinaryMatrix(user);
        i++;
    }
}

function bytesToAddress(bytes memory bys) private pure returns (address addr) {
    assembly {
        addr := mload(add(bys, 20))
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please share the contract code.

Answer (score 4):

The really cool thing about smart contracts is their immutable nature. They can't be altered or changed which gives everyone confidence. So much so that the data in some contracts begin to take on the characteristics of assets. The flip side is the owner has zero special privileges unless they are explicitly coded into the contract.

Money cannot leave the contract unless there is a function in the contract that allows money to leave.

The contract cannot be stopped unless there is a function in the contract that allows someone to stop it.

You get the idea.

Ownership means nothing unless the contract includes functions that give the owner special permission. Indeed, if there were special permissions built-in for every case, that would be a centralized design which Ethereum is not.

The decentralized structure makes the contracts very clear about what will *ever* be possible and, inversly, what will *always* be impossible.

You should post the contract code or a link to it so the experts here can see what the code says in your particular case.

Hope it helps.